# Mac OS X: Hide showing the application window after reboot

Tags: macos

I have developed an Mac OS X application recently. This application works in the background and launching at Login items in every reboot. I have used the sample code from here->
https://gist.github.com/jquave/LaunchAtLoginController/blob/c8ae6dd2b8b0a2864ede0366991f43b580b65124/LaunchAtLoginController.m

Using this code, as it starts the app running automatically after reboot is happening on the machine. Now i have the requirement that not to show the app window(only the window) after every reboot but app can run in the background as it is. For this, i have used `kLSSharedFileListLoginItemHidden` as mentioned and updated in this URL and source. But, even after adding this hidden login item property, still the application window is opening every after reboot the machine. How to avoid opening the login item app window (only the window), every after the reboot programmatically? I am using Lion OS 10.7.3. Please advise.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this is Jameson Quave. I authored the above mentioned github file changes. I think one flaw with my approach is it may not be user safe. Are you and admin in the account you're testing with?